# I want to change content of my subscription div without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to change the content of my subscription div,like when user is already subscribed I want to change the div color into red and to tell a message that 'you are already subscribed'.I know it can be done with ajax but I don't know anything about Ajax.

Here is the PHP inserted div

```
<?php
echo ';
<div id="sub">
<form method="post" action="subscription.inc.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" `enter code here`onclick="myAjax()">Subscirbe</button>
</form>
</div>
';
?>
```

This is the PHP code that should be run on clicking

```
<?php 
include 'conn.php';
include 'sub.php';
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
      $sql="INSERT INTO `subscribe` (`id`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$email');";

      $emailcheck="SELECT * FROM `subscribe` WHERE email='ayush.antino@gmail.com'";
      $doubleemail=mysqli_query($conn,$emailcheck);
      $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($doubleemail);
      if ($num_rows>0) {
        header("Location:sub.php?subscribe=alreadyexist");
        exit();
      }elseif ($num_rows==0) {
        if (!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
         echo "please enter valid email";
      } else {
         mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         header("Location:sub.php?subscribe=success");
         exit();
      }

  }
}
?>
```

How should I refresh the message 'you are already subscribed' without refreshing the page

Comment: readabout jquery ajax

Comment: This is the key concept behind ajax: making http requests from the web page without navigating. I really suggest you to take a look at some guides (see [Ajax - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)), make an attempt and then edit the question if you need more help.

Comment: It will take time to learn Ajax completely and I already started learning ajax but the point is I don't have much time that's why I need code to solve the problem instantly

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this..

```
 <div id="sub">
    <form method="post" action="subscription.inc.php">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" `enter code here`onclick="myAjax()">Subscirbe</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    <script>
checkSubscribe();
    function checkSubscribe() {

            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            $('#sub').css('background-color:red;')
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "checkuser.php", true);
            xmlhttp.send();

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: what should I write in place of checkuser.php